# JavaScript 'strict mode' not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, strict

```
var test = function() {

    'use strict';

    var mapNames = {
        'name': 'City Name:',
        'coord.lat': 'Latitute:'
    };  

    for (var key in mapNames) {

        var names;

        if (mapNames[key]) {
            name = mapNames[key];
        } else {
            name = key;
        }
    }

    console.log(name);

}

test();
```

In the code above I made a mistake by declaring variable `names` and using `name` instead. I thought 'strict' mode would catch it but it didn't. Shouldn't this throw an error in this case?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A `name` global variable already exists, unrelated to your code; it represents the name of the current window, so you are assigning to an already existing variable.

```
window.name; // the name of the current window for cross-window communication
```

Everything on `window` is declared as a global - so it is not reference-erroring since it is assigning to a variable in an outer scope.

Super confusing :D

- [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) on MDN.
- [HTML Specification, window name property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#window).

---

`"use strict"` would prevent defining new global variables, here we are performing an assignment to an existing variable, think of it as `name` is in the global scope, like `window.Blob`, `window.console` and so on.

Comment: shouldn't `"use strict"` prevent exactly that?

Comment: @JanDvorak `"use strict"` would prevent defining new global variables, here we are performing an assignment to _an existing variable_, think of it as `name` is in the global scope, like `window.Blob`, `window.console` and so on.

Comment: ah, browser already provides a variable with that name. Can we have a super-strict mode where globals can't be accessed by name? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think so that there would be any way.

Comment: `typeof document.name` is always `'string'`

Comment: It's not only globals, it's the outer scope (recursively) where you defined (in this case) your function. You need an extra language feature to explicitly tell that you want to access an outer scope.. (e.g. `global` in php and python)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The point is that even if you don't define a variable called `name`, the browser does that for you in the global scope.

Comment: Also note that the strict mode catches the error just fine in node (because there's no "window").

Comment: @georg yes, strict mode errors (as it should) in any environemt where the host object does not define a `name` property.

Comment: BTW, it might be clearer if *`name` global variable* is changed to *`name` global **property***. This merging of variables and properties only happens for the global object/environment record.